# How to clamp a SwiftUI spring animation for a smooth "snap" after releasing a DragGesture?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-animation

I have a view that I want to drag across the screen using a DragGesture. When the gesture ends, I want the view to seamlessly animate (snap) to a fixed position. Additionally the view should be clamped to the edges of the screen, and not translate off-screen

As you can see from the clip, the clamp works when dragging the view. However, when I release it and the spring animation kicks in, the view translates off screen.

The reason for choosing a spring animation is because I'm able to pass it an `initialVelocity` - this helps with the seamless transition between the gesture and the animation.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

[image: video of clamping]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    private let viewHeight: CGFloat = 100
    @State private var position: CGFloat = 100 / 2
    
    private func clamp(_ value: CGFloat, min minValue: CGFloat, max maxValue: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        return min(max(value, minValue), maxValue)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            
            let snapTop: CGFloat = viewHeight / 2
            let snapBottom: CGFloat = geometry.size.height + geometry.safeAreaInsets.bottom + geometry.safeAreaInsets.top - (viewHeight / 2)
             
            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.red)
                    .frame(height: viewHeight)
                    .position(x: geometry.size.width / 2, y: clamp(position, min: snapTop, max: snapBottom))
                    .gesture(
                        DragGesture()
                            .onChanged { value in
                                position = value.location.y
                            }
                            .onEnded { value in
                                let velocity = clamp(
                                    abs(value.predictedEndLocation.y - value.location.y) / 100,
                                    min: 0,
                                    max: 20
                                )
        
                                withAnimation(
                                    .interpolatingSpring(
                                        stiffness: 100,
                                        damping: 6,
                                        initialVelocity: velocity
                                    )
                                ) {
                                    self.position = snapBottom
                                }
                            }
                    )
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. The key is that .updating doesn't make any permanent changes. The actual state only gets updated in .onEnded.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    private let viewHeight: CGFloat = 100
    @State private var position: CGFloat = 100 / 2
    @GestureState(resetTransaction: Transaction(animation: .easeOut)) private var dragHeight: CGFloat = 0

    private func clamp(_ value: CGFloat, min minValue: CGFloat, max maxValue: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        return min(max(value, minValue), maxValue)
    }

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            let snapTop: CGFloat = viewHeight / 2
            let snapBottom: CGFloat = geometry.size.height + geometry.safeAreaInsets.bottom + geometry.safeAreaInsets.top - (viewHeight / 2)

            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.red)
                    .frame(height: viewHeight)
                    .position(x: geometry.size.width / 2, y: clamp(position + dragHeight, min: snapTop, max: snapBottom))
                    .gesture(
                        DragGesture()
                            .updating($dragHeight) { value, state, _ in
                                state = value.translation.height
                            }
                            .onEnded { value in
                                withAnimation(.easeOut) {
                                    position = position + value.predictedEndTranslation.height > geometry.size.height / 2 ? snapBottom : snapTop
                                }
                            }
                    )
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea()
        }
    }
}
```